# SqlConnection.Open() hangs on Windows XP

Tags: c#, permissions, sqlconnection, freeze

I have a simple piece of code in a .NET console application that tries to open an SQL connection to a server:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("<my connection string>"))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

It works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 machine, but on my other machine running Windows XP x64 the call to Open() hangs indefinitely.

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can diagnose the cause? I am running the program from an administrator account on both computers.

EDIT: Ok, it seems to be a firewall issue. I've connected my Windows 7 machine to the same internet connection as the Windows XP machine and now it hangs too... what ports do I need to open to let SQL traffic through, and how do I go about opening them?

EDIT: In case anyone's interested, my network admin was blocking outgoing traffic to port 1433 out of fear of the Slammer worm ...

Comment: Are you sure it's indefinitely? You should be receiving a TimeOutException (default is 30 seconds). Also, can you connect to the SQL Server instance from the WinXP machine using something else (like SSMS Express)? Is the SQL Server instance a named instance?

Comment: If it truly is being blocked, I'd check Windows Firewall or another firewall product to see if it's letting traffic out on the SQL ports

Comment: @bitxwise earlier today I've let it run for over 4 hours. I didn't get a timeout.

Comment: @HighCommander4: That's weird, there should be a timeout by default. Have you disabled it?

Comment: @Matti The timeout was set to 1 hour. I changed it to 2 seconds, but it doesn't time out after 2 seconds, it just hangs.

Comment: @HighCommander: There's a difference between connection timeout and command timeout, make sure you're setting the connection timeout. Also, is the SQL Server instance a named instance? This is important as if your DNS settings don't include the domain that the SQL Server instance is on, then your WinXP machine won't be able to find it...

Comment: @bitxwise How do I tell whether the SQL Server instance is a named instance?

Comment: @HighCommander4: Hm, post your connection string (without the actual username/password if you're using SQL authentication)

Comment: @bitxwise: Data Source=database2.ehost-services.com;Initial Catalog=<redacted>;User ID=<redacted>;Password=<redacted>; Connect Timeout=2000; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=20000"

Comment: @HighCommander4: I can successfully ping the data source address you posted as well as attempt to connect to it. I'll post something below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can ping and attempt to connect to database2.ehost-services.com (though I received a Login failed), let's try to simplify your connection string:

```
Data Source=database2.ehost-services.com;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;User ID=myUser;Password=myP@ssword;
```

**EDIT**

To answer your question regarding why your connection string did not time out, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) describes the `pooling` attribute of the connection string as follows:

> When the value of this key is set to
>   true, any newly created connection
>   will be added to the pool when closed
>   by the application. In a next attempt
>   to open the same connection, that
>   connection will be drawn from the
>   pool.
>
> Connections are considered the same if
>   they have the same connection string.
>   Different connections have different
>   connection strings.
>
> The value of this key can be "true",
>   "false", "yes", or "no".

So I'm thinking perhaps your connection instance wasn't actually pooled yet to time out.

**EDIT**

From your error message it looks like you're using NAMED PIPES instead of TCP/IP. Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892.aspx) can help you out (use SQL Server Configuration Manager to select your protocol). Check under [SQL Native Client 9.0/10.0 Configuration] and you should see a list of protocols. Make sure TCP/IP is listed with an order before Named Pipes and is also ENABLED. For example, my order of 1 - 3 is Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes, and VIA is disabled.

**EDIT**

Try creating an Alias with TCP/IP protocal selected and connecting to your alias? You can do this also using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

**EDIT**

As the OP has resolved the issue, I did make the comment on someone else's answer:

> A security policy that blocks outgoing
>   would have to be explicitly created

and SOB, that's what it was - network admin blocked outgoing traffic on port 1433. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: With this connection string, it times out after about 30 seconds and displays the following error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Comment: Can you ping database2.ehost-services.com from the WinXP machine?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is it about this modified connection string that causes it to time out while the other one didn't?

Comment: Do you have remote access to the SQL Server box?

Comment: Assuming your Data Source is an established host, I would think they'd have the environment configured properly. Can you use SSMS or SSMSE to connect to the Data Source from your WinXP machine?

Comment: I get the same error (`A network-related or instance-specific error ...`) when I try to connect using SSMSE.

Comment: Try connecting with the wrong username/password. I get a "Login failed" so if you don't get the same, the problem is probably on your machine.

Comment: Still the same error when I use the wrong username/password, not "Login failed". I guess the problem really is with this machine, or more specifically, with its Internet connection...

Comment: Updated answer w/ MSDN documentation on selecting a protocol.

Comment: My protocols are exactly as you described - 1, 2, 3 are Shared Memory, TCP/IP, and Named Pipes, and they're all enabld, and VIA is disabled.

Comment: Updated answer w/ suggestion of creating an alias for your host's SQL Server instance.

Comment: With the alias, I get a slightly different error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)`

Comment: I figured it out: my network admin was blocking outgoing traffic to port 1433. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your database server is accessible from both of your PCs? Have you tried connecting to it from the problematic system using another tool?

And how long have you let it run?

Comment: You are correct, it seems to be an issue with my connection on the Windows XP machine... see my edit above.

Comment: @HighCommander4: In the cases I've run into, port TCP/1433 has been enough.

Comment: I thought TCP/1433 needs to be open on the server side, but not the client side...

Comment: @bitxwise: Well, he asked for a port. Perhaps he has a firewall that blocks outgoing connections somewhere?

Comment: A security policy that blocks outgoing would have to be explicitly created (and against his SQL Server instance's address). So, I'm thinking it's more a domain issue...